# load data terminated by does not import

Tags: mysql

Table:
ID int not null primary key auto_increment
number int not null unique

my file:
111
222
333

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE MyTable fields terminated by '\n' (number); - everything works fine. But if I have:

file:
111;222;333

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE MyTable fields terminated by ';' (number); - it imports only 111 and stops. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a list of values separated by a ";" into a single table field use this.  This will basically treat each value as a separate record.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE MyTable 
LINES TERMINATED BY ';'
(number) 
;
```

If you want to insert the 3 fields from the file into the first three fields in the table, remove `(number)`.  By including `(number)` you were specifying that you only wanted to insert data only into the `number` field.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE MyTable fields terminated by ';';
```

If you want to insert the three fields from the file into three specific fields in the table (not necessarily the first three) you need to list all three.  For example if you wanted to insert them into the fields `number`, `field2` and `field3` the command would be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt' IGNORE 
INTO TABLE MyTable fields terminated by ';' (number, field2, field3);
```

Comment: I want to put all data to one column, 'number'. But table has two columns, first one is: ID (not null, int, auto_increment, primary key), second is number (integer, unique, not null). If I remove (number) at the end of the statement, it tries to insert data to ID as well, which I do not want. I want ID to auto_increment with every data imported from file. Beside, as I said, if every data is in a new line and I use terminate by '\n' it works fine. But if values are one after another, seperated by ';' it fails, and I don't know why

Comment: Ok, I added that scenario at the top of my response.  See if that works for you.  It should load a ";" delimited list into the `number` field in a table.